# TYPO3 won't accept images with the extension JPG

Tags: typo3

I can upload files with the extension JPG and jpg to the filelist, but only files with extension jpg can be inserted in content elements. As soon as it is capital letters, I get an error.

Is that a bug or where did I miss to check something?

I use TYPO3 7.1.0

The question is also asked here: https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/m/735666/#msg_735666

Comment: Are you sure it's "JPG" and not "JPEG"? I remember some issues with that in general, not related to typo3 but might a check worth.

Comment: It is JPG. I wonder if it is possible to force lowercase on upload?

Answer (score 0):

Via `List` module open the *zero page* (this highest one) find all `File Storage` records and in each check the `Uses case sensitive identifiers` flag - that should help, but maybe you'll need to upload the files once again.

If it won't help try in other direction ;)